# How to check whether number is divisible by another number WITHOUT conditional check (if, ternary, etc.) in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, division, conditional-operator

I have a number, for example, X. I want to check if it is divisible by Y (another number). If it is divisible by Y, I need to return 1, otherwise 0. But I am not allowed to use if condition, ternary operator, equals, etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: `return number % 3 == 0` perhaps?

Comment: Is `x % 3 == 0`  good enough?

Comment: Or `return (number / 3) * 3 == number` if you need it more fancy.

Comment: Is it possible to return 1 if it is divisible and 0 if it is not divisible? If yes, how? Just asking?

Comment: You could use a switch expression: `return (number % 3) switch { 0 => 1, _ => 0 }`

Comment: But conditional check is not allowed.

Comment: This assigment is probably to teach you that the result of `x == y` or `x != y` is a `bool` value, to demonstrate that you can obtain a `bool` without using `if` or `?:`.

Comment: For the fun: calculate 1 / (1 + e^(10000(mod(x, 3)))

Should work for integers, but will always be wrong at some point for floats (increase the 10000 value for more precision).

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916524/analytic-approximations-of-the-step-function

Comment: Q: _" I need to return true, otherwise false"_ , Comment: _"Is it possible to return 1 if it is divisible and 0 if it is not divisible?"_ - which one is it? If the latter and X is `int` and you are not allowed to use any conditional: `return results[x%3];` where `results` is `int[] results = {0,1,1};`

Comment: @MatthewWatson, that's not 100% true.

Comment: @AjinkyaJagtap I edited the comment and added a way to do it.

Comment: @Fildor, if we need to check this condition for some number Y instead of specific number 3, how can we modify the solution?

Comment: That's a good excercise for you ... :D

Answer (score 5):

This expression returns true if the variable `X` is divisible by 3

```cs
X % 3 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator

```
return ((double)number) % 3.0d == 0
```

Comment: Any particular reason to cast to `double`?

Answer (score -1):

Without using *any* conditionals, *including* `==` (which is actually also a conditional underneath)

> Bit-twiddling based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887208/reducing-an-integer-to-1-if-it-is-not-equal-to-0)

```cs
var mod = unchecked((uint)(a % b));
mod = ((mod - 1U) & ~mod) >> 31;
return Unsafe.As<uint, bool>(ref mod);
// for earlier versions of .Net, do the below in an unsafe method
return *(bool*)&mod;
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrGaFY)

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Works for me in fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrGaFY, please show how it's not working for you

Comment: Ohh, I figured out that Unsafe is available in .NET 6 but not in .NET 4.7.2

Comment: Yes, on earlier versions you would have to use unsafe pointer dereferencing